# Crontab isn't running

Tags: linux, cron

My crontab isn't running and I'm trying to figure out why.  I've created a symbolic link within `/etc/cron.d` to `/var/www/mysite.crontab`

```
user@ip-xxxxxxxxxx:/etc/cron.d$ ll
total 20
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Apr 11 03:48 ./
drwxr-xr-x 96 root root 4096 Apr 16 00:50 ../
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   30 Apr 11 03:47 mysite.crontab -> /var/www/mysite.crontab
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  124 Feb 27  2012 drupal7
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  544 Sep 12  2012 php5
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  102 Apr  2  2012 .placeholder
```

The actual cron file is...

```
#Purge old deals
4 1 * * * www-data wget -q -O- http://www.mysite.com/cron/clean > /dev/null 2>&1;
```

Comment: Try changing `wget` for `/bin/wget` or whatever comes from `which wget`. Also, make a simple test `* * * * * /usr/bin/touch /tmp/file` to see if it is a problem on crontab or script.

Comment: @fedorqui - I restarted cron via `sudo service cron restart` to ensure the latest changes were loaded and the file isn't being touched :-\

Comment: Is the `/usr/sbin/cron` daemon running?

Comment: Uhms so it is problem on the crontab configuration, not on this particular cronjob. Why did you created this symbolic link? What about just adding an entry in `/etc/crontab` with `crontab -e`? Also, maybe in [su] would be able to give you a better help.

Comment: I host many sites, so keeping the crontab with the site files helps a lot with organization.

Comment: @fedorqui 1. `crontab -e` doesn't edit `/etc/crontab`, 2. using `/etc/cron.d/` is a perfectly valid concern, as many packages do so by putting their cron files there...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oddly enough the problem is with the name of the file. You are not permitted to use a `.` as a part of the name of the file when present in the `/etc/cron.d` dirctory.

The logic for this is in the [`database.c`](http://anonscm.debian.org/gitweb/?p=pkg-cron/pkg-cron.git;a=blob;f=database.c;h=b05e3b6679c38873e02298f5d2f5a2429bc3f2bb;hb=refs/heads/master#l531) file, in the function `valid_name`. Renaming the file to something like mysite_crontab should fix the issue.

In general, the filename should probably just be a simple name `mysite` the fact that it's in this directory implies that it's a cron file already.

The file that is being pointed to must be owned by root, this is stated in the man page for the support of the `/etc/cron.d` directory:

> Support  for  `/etc/cron.d` is included in the cron daemon itself, which handles this location as the system-wide crontab spool. This directory can contain any file defining tasks following the format used in `/etc/crontab`, i.e. unlike the user cron spool, these files must provide the username to run the task as in the task definition.
>
> Files in this directory **have to be owned by root**, do not need to be executable (they are configuration files, just like `/etc/crontab`) and must conform to the same naming convention as used by run-parts(8):  they must  consist  solely  of  upper-  and lower-case letters, digits, underscores, and hyphens. This means that they **cannot contain any dots**.  If the `-l` option is specified to cron (this option can be setup through `/etc/default/cron`, see below), then they must conform to the LSB namespace specification, exactly as in the `--lsbsysinit` option in run-parts.
>
> The intended purpose of this feature is to allow packages that require finer control of their scheduling than the `/etc/cron.{hourly,daily,weekly,monthly}` directories to add a crontab file  to  /etc/cron.d.  Such files should be named after the package that supplies them.

Comment: I've made the filename changes and restarted cron and don't have any evidence that it's working.

Comment: When I said 'the name of the file' I meant that the entry in /etc/cron.d must follow the naming convention. Did you remake the symlink. If testing crontabs, I generally put in a run every minute cron job updating a timestamp file that I can check

Comment: I did rename the file from `mysite.cron` to `mysite_cron`.  I also used @fedorqui's suggested test: `* * * * * /usr/bin/touch /tmp/file`

Comment: Because these are non-user specific files, you need to add a username to the line before the command. so `* * * * * www-data date >/tmp/file` would probably be better

Comment: My fault, I did have the it running as user `www-data` and it never ran

Comment: at this point, I would run an strace against cron, delete the symbolic link and recreate it - if the output of the strace indicates that the file was processed, then the file is successfully being loaded (you should also check for other files being processed in that directory). Additionally the target file needs to be owned by root (that's a condition listed in the man page)